# Split images losing color when saving RasterBrick array as *jpg

Tags: jpeg, raster, r-raster

```
#Packages
library(raster)  
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(jpeg)
```

I have a RGB color *jpg image:

```
## Open my RGB image 
 path<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG" # Image path
download.file(path, "IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG", mode = "wb")
rc<-stack(raster("IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG")) #Open as a raster and stack
plot(rc)
```

[image: bigimage]

When I try to split in 16 images of equal size:

```
# This function spatially aggregates the original raster
# it turns each aggregated cell into a polygon
# then the extent of each polygon is used to crop
# the original raster.
# The function returns a list with all the pieces
# it saves and plots each piece
# The arguments are:
# raster = raster to be chopped            (raster object)
# ppside = pieces per side                 (integer)
# save   = write raster                    (TRUE or FALSE)
# plot   = do you want to plot the output? (TRUE or FALSE)
SplitRas <- function(raster,ppside,save,plot){
  h        <- ceiling(ncol(raster)/ppside)
  v        <- ceiling(nrow(raster)/ppside)
  agg      <- aggregate(raster,fact=c(h,v))
  agg[]    <- 1:ncell(agg)
  agg_poly <- rasterToPolygons(agg)
  names(agg_poly) <- "polis"
  r_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:ncell(agg)){
    e1          <- extent(agg_poly[agg_poly$polis==i,])
    r_list[[i]] <- crop(raster,e1)
  }
  if(save==T){
    for(i in 1:length(r_list)){
      options(max.print=999999) 
      #EBImage::writeImage(as.array(r_list[[i]]/255), paste0("sample_",i,".jpg",sep=""),quality = 100)
      writeJPEG(as.array(r_list[[i]]/255), target = paste0("sample_",i,".jpg",sep=""),quality = 1,color.space="RGBA")
    }
  }
  return(r_list)
}

#Slip RGB raster in 16 subimages
splitRBG<-SplitRas(raster=rc,ppside=4,save=TRUE)
#
```

The results are greyscaled images, eg. 1 (`sample_1.jpg`) of the 16 images:
[image]

I try to make a lot of changes in `writeJPEG()` function (something is wrong in the `as.array(r_list[[i]]/255)`code or in the `color.space`) without success, please any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: split each RGB channel in a individual  `raster` layer (`rst.blue,rst.green nad rst.red`) and `stack` before the crop operation with `SplitRas` custom function and works!!

```
#Packages
library(raster)  
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(jpeg)

## download RGB image 
path<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG" # Image path
download.file(path, "IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG", mode = "wb")

# Open jpeg file
jpg<-readJPEG("IMG_191022_134242_0000_RGB.JPG")

# Convert imagedata to raster
rst.blue <- raster(jpg[,,1])
rst.green <- raster(jpg[,,2])
rst.red <- raster(jpg[,,3])
rc<-stack(rst.blue, rst.green, rst.red)


# This function spatially aggregates the original raster
# it turns each aggregated cell into a polygon
# then the extent of each polygon is used to crop
# the original raster.
# The function returns a list with all the pieces
# it saves and plots each piece
# The arguments are:
# raster = raster to be chopped            (raster object)
# ppside = pieces per side                 (integer)
# save   = write raster                    (TRUE or FALSE)
# plot   = do you want to plot the output? (TRUE or FALSE)
SplitRas <- function(raster,ppside,save,plot){
  h        <- ceiling(ncol(raster)/ppside)
  v        <- ceiling(nrow(raster)/ppside)
  agg      <- aggregate(raster,fact=c(h,v))
  agg[]    <- 1:ncell(agg)
  agg_poly <- rasterToPolygons(agg)
  names(agg_poly) <- "polis"
  r_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:ncell(agg)){
    e1          <- extent(agg_poly[agg_poly$polis==i,])
    r_list[[i]] <- crop(raster,e1)
  }
  if(save==T){
    for(i in 1:length(r_list)){
      writeJPEG(as.array(r_list[[i]]), target = paste0("sample_",i,".jpg",sep=""),quality = 1)
    }
  }
  return(r_list)
}

#Slip RGB raster in 4 equal parts
splitRBG<-SplitRas(raster=rc,ppside=4,save=TRUE)
#
```